# Can fancybox do a simple slide show, like Skitter?

Tags: fancybox

I'd like to have a large banner image appear on my page when it loads and then be able to click on the right or left side of the image to roll through several other large images, as Skitter does.  Can fancybox 2 do this?  All the Fancybox examples I've seen let you click a thumbnail, which then opens to a full size image, with navigation arrows to roll through other images you've defined to be in that slideshow.

Thanks

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/y5mzrkna/show/ ?

Comment: Sort of. But the container needs to be just one of many components at the top of the page, as [here](http://muzzybella.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fancybox(galllery_img_arr, {
        loop: true,
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'elastic',
        nextEffect: 'fade',
        prevEffect: 'fade',
        arrows:false,
        closeBtn: true,
        closeClick: false,
        openSpeed: 150,
        closeSpeed: 150,
        overlayShow: true,
        overlayOpacity: 0.8,
        centerOnScroll: true,
        title: 'Your Slider Title'
    });
```

Where galllery_img_arr is an array of images. It contains url of images. #enlarge is the ID of button. When you click on this button, it pop ups images with Next/Prev arrows. When you click on Next/Prev arrows, it slides image one by one.